# Show $\sin(x+h) \cdot \cos x - \cos(x+h) \cdot \sin x = \sin h$ (without limits please - straight trigonometry only).

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I've tried an algebraic approach using the identity

$\sin(x) = \sin(x+h-h) = \sin(x+h)\cos(h) - \cos(x+h)\sin(h)$, leading to a complicated expression I'm having trouble simplifying:

$[\sin(x)\cos(h) + \cos(x)\sin(h)]\cos(x) - [\cos(x)\cos(h) - \sin(x)\sin(h)][\sin(x+h)\cos(h)-\cos(x+h)\sin(h)]$

(further expansion of $\sin(x+h)$ and $\cos(x+h)$ in this expression did not help me).

Use of this identity was a hint in the book I came across this in, What is Mathematics, by Courant and Robbins, p. 422.

Note: Since posting I realized how to show symbolically in the updated diagram below, which has been updated since posting (including also the correct algebraic answer given by @Andre Nicholas).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $\sin(a-b)=\sin a\cos b -\cos a\sin b$. Let $a=x+h$ and $b=x$.

**Remark:** You used precisely the same approach, except that instead of using $\sin(x+h-x)$, as above, you used $\sin(x+h-h)$.

Comment: Aha...Sidetracked into the weeds again!

Comment: Yes, you were one symbol away from a one-line proof.

Comment: The OP diagram has now been updated with the continuation of the symbolic (or geometrical) approach also - showing this in a completely different (if longer) way.

Comment: The geometric way is nice. Another good way is to go to complex numbers, using $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$.